# Online version of most up-to-date UCC?

Tags: contract-law, ucc

Is there an online version of the most up to date Uniform Commercial Code? I'd prefer a free copy but would be happy with any electronic copy.

Comment: Is the version provided by Cornell not up to date? https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc

Comment: Ah, I see... They display the version with the most widespread adoption. Hmm.